# Raspberry Pi400

Tags: screen, reset

My raspberry Pi400 is showing a rainbow screen and I don’t have a device where I can plug in the sd card to fix it. Can I fix it by buying a new sd card from pi hut and will that allow me to start a new account on the pi

Comment: A new or reformatted SDCard will set your RPi400 back like it just came out of the box. But, you should look at fixing the broken filesystem with `fsck` on any Linux system or (at a pinch) fixing the boot partition using Windows (do not reformat, all you're doing is a file system check on the FAT partition).

Answer (score 1):

I am not trying to push a particular brand or product, but the answer to your question is that you need some hardware to read your Pi's SD card. You can do that with a very cheap SD to USB converter, like this:

https://www.canakit.com/mini-micro-sd-usb-reader.html

I do not work for canakit nor am I affiliated with them in any way, but this is what you need to perform diagnostics on your SD card from a normal PC. Feel free to get something like this elsewhere if you like...

You can also use something like this to simply re-install your Raspberry Pi OS or to set up a new SD card to use with your Pi.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Those adapters are cheap and plentiful anywhere that sells consumer electronics.  Even if you don't have another computer, you could borrow one from someone who'll let you install the Pi imager and flash the card with a new install, this doesn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another computer, doesn’t matter whether it’s linux, Windows or Mac, you can reformat the SD card if it’s not physically damaged. If you want to recover the card check thisÑ

https://7datarecovery.com/blog/sd-card-health-check/

Another solution is to install an operative system on the card, directly from the Internet:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#install-over-the-network

You can install the OS on a USB device or a SD card.

All possibilities are described here:
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html